# Tensorflow installation problem on Windows 7

Tags: tensorflow, failed-installation

Can I install Tensorflow package to my **Windows 7 32-bit Service Pack 1** System?? I got following error while installing it.

[Refer this link for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdLH1.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of linking a screenshot, please format and paste your error into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Tensorflow is only supported and tested in 64-bit OS only. Unfortunately, your system seems to be not compatible.

For more information: https://www.tensorflow.org/install